# visual studio can't signing keystore key

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

hi I am tired to try creating android keystore in xamarin visual studio 2017
I try many solutions but not work with me

here I record video explain my biggest problem

[vedio link on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2MLjGAMU5TQ)

best regards

Comment: I posted an answer for your problm, please try it to see whether it can help.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced your problem and was able to solve this problem by the following 2 steps:

1) Make sure the `Enable Multi-Dex` is enabled (Check this in Android Options):

[image]

2) Add MultiDexApplication to Android Manifest:

```
<application android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"></application>
```

[image]

Comment: tnx bro i solved .. i was use hijri date in my pc i changed to gregorian calendar and work

Comment: I do not have the calendar issue, but did reproduce the same issue as you have and solved it in the way above. But anyway, glad it is solved.